# What are the best practices for using Assembly Attributes?

Tags: .net, assemblies, attributes, assemblyinfo

I have a solution with multiple project. I am trying to optimize AssemblyInfo.cs files by linking one solution wide assembly info file. What are the best practices for doing this? Which attributes should be in solution wide file and which are project/assembly specific?

---

*Edit: If you are interested there is a follow up question [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin)*

Answer (score 215, accepted):

We're using a global file called GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs and a local one called AssemblyInfo.cs. The global file contains the following attributes:

```
 [assembly: AssemblyProduct("Your Product Name")]

 [assembly: AssemblyCompany("Your Company")]
 [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2008 ...")]
 [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("Your Trademark - if applicable")]

 #if DEBUG
 [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
 #else
 [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
 #endif

 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("This is set by build process")]
 [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("This is set by build process")]
```

The local AssemblyInfo.cs contains the following attributes:

```
 [assembly: AssemblyTitle("Your assembly title")]
 [assembly: AssemblyDescription("Your assembly description")]
 [assembly: AssemblyCulture("The culture - if not neutral")]

 [assembly: ComVisible(true/false)]

 // unique id per assembly
 [assembly: Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
```

You can add the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs using the following procedure:

- Select **Add/Existing Item...** in the context menu of the project
- Select GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs
- Expand the Add-Button by clicking on that little down-arrow on the right hand
- Select "Add As Link" in the buttons drop down list

Comment: what is the purpose of keeping the old AssemblyInfo.cs file(s) around? When I automate my build version stamp in GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs, how does that update the AssemblyInfo.cs file(s) I have in my solution?

Comment: @Devtron The individual AssemblyInfo files should provide information unique to the assembly that they reside in (e.g. title, description and culture, as in the example above). Common entries, such as the product name and versioning information should be removed (and will cause a compiler error if they are duplicated). Ideally, the AssemblyInfo files will not be updated by the build process.

Comment: The `AssemblyCultureAttribute` deserves a better explanation.  The attribute should best be absent completely (unless this is a satellite assembly).  When using satelite assemblies on a large scale, one may need three, not two levels of assembly info files (global, main assembly, and satellite assembly which only specifies the culture in this case).

Answer (score 21):

In my case, we're building a product for which we have a Visual Studio solution, with various components in their own projects. The common attributes go. In the solution, there are about 35 projects, and a common assembly info (CommonAssemblyInfo.cs), which has the following attributes:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Product Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2007 Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("Company")]

//This shows up as Product Version in Windows Explorer
//We make this the same for all files in a particular product version. And increment it globally for all projects.
//We then use this as the Product Version in installers as well (for example built using Wix).
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.9.2.0")]
```

The other attributes such as AssemblyTitle, AssemblyVersion etc, we supply on a per-assembly basis. When building an assembly both AssemblyInfo.cs and CommonAssemblyInfo.cs are built into each assembly. This gives us the best of both worlds where you may want to have some common attributes for all projects and specific values for some others.

Hope that helps.

Comment: do you have 35+ entries in your build configuration to handle this? Seems rather redundant. What if you add 2 or 3 new projects, does that break your build until you add them to the Versioning task?

Comment: @D3vtr0n, why would a “build configuration” (what do you mean by that) need so many entries? I assume this file is included in each .csproj through `<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Common\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs"/>`, an MSBuild directive that may even be in a shared `Common.targets` file. Yay code reuse.

Answer (score 16):

The solution presented by @JRoppert is almost the same as what I do. The only difference is that I put the following lines in the local AssemblyInfo.cs file as they can vary with each assembly:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("This is set by build process")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("This is set by build process")]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

I also (generally) use one common assembly info per solution, with the assumption that one solution is a single product line/releasable product. The common assembly info file also has:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.9.2.0")]
```

Which will set the "ProductVersion" value displayed by Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 8):

[MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) contains a custom task called AssemblyInfo which you can use to generate your assemblyinfo.cs.  It requires a little hand-editing of your csproj files to use, but is worthwhile.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion using a GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs is more trouble than it's worth, because you need to modify every project file and remember to modify every new project, whereas you get an AssemblyInfo.cs by default.

For changes to global values (i.e. Company, Product etc) the changes are usually so infrequent and simple to manage I don't think [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) should be a consideration. Just run the following MSBuild script (dependent on the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://mikefourie.github.io/MSBuildExtensionPack/)) when you want to manually change the values in all projects as a one-off:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="UpdateAssemblyInfo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <AllAssemblyInfoFiles Include="..\**\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Project="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" />

  <Target Name="UpdateAssemblyInfo">
    <Message Text="%(AllAssemblyInfoFiles.FullPath)" />
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo 
        AssemblyInfoFiles="@(AllAssemblyInfoFiles)"
        AssemblyCompany="Company"
        AssemblyProduct="Product"
        AssemblyCopyright="Copyright"
        ... etc ...
        />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: I think you are chasing a nonexistent problem, because you can easily inject the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs with a simple Directory.Build.props file, which also covers all projects you add in the future.

Answer (score 3):

To share a file between multiple projects you can add an existing file as a link.

To do this, add an existing file, and click on "Add as Link" in the file selector.[image: Add As Link]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://laurent.etiemble.free.fr/dotclear/images/AddLinkedFile03_tn.png))</sub>

As for what to put in the shared file, I would suggest putting things that would be shared across assemblies. Things like copyright, company, perhaps version.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have found useful is to generate the AssemblyVersion elements (etc) by applying token-substitution in the pre-build phase.

I use TortoiseSvn, and it is easy to use its `SubWCRev.exe` to turn a template `AssemblyInfo.wcrev` into `AssemblyInfo.cs`.  The relevant line in the template might look something like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.3.$WCREV$.$WCMODS?1:0$$WCUNVER?1:0$")]
```

The third element is then the revision number.  I use the fourth element to check I haven't forgotten to commit any new or changed files (the fourth element is 00 if it is all OK).

By the way, add `AssemblyInfo.wcrev` to your version control and **ignore** `AssemblyInfo.cs` if you use this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single AseemblyInfo.cs file for multiple projects is not recommended.
The AssemblyInfo file includes information that might be relevant only for that specific assembly. The two most obvious pieces of information are the `AssemblyTitle` and `AssemblyVersion`.

A better solution might be to use `targets` file, which are handled by the MSBuild, in order to "inject" assembly attributes to more than one project.

Comment: what if you have 20+ projects? That requires me to maintain 20+ entries in my build configuration, just for Versioning. That seems really lame. What if I add 2 or 3 new projects? That will definitely break the build process...Any ideas how to solution that?

Comment: @D3vtr0n I think the idea is to generate the relevate Assembly dynamically and not maintain individual configurations for each project.  Community Tasks, i think, handles that case.